# Trouble running code from Jupyter (name 'pkg_resources' is not defined)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter, setuptools

I'm a statistician that is new to Python. I had written a Python program that worked successfully on my laptop, which recently had to be reformatted due an error in Windows.

My Python program was recovered and stored in a new folder, and the technicians also created a generic 'User' for Windows instead of the old account I used to have. Now, when I attempt to run this program -- which was also retrieved and was stored in a new directory by the technicians -- I get the following message:

```
NameError: name 'pkg_resources' is not defined
```

I would appreciate any simple guidance as to whether I need to change directories, file names, or undertake other admin actions to get my code to work.[See error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh7LT.png)

Comment: Have you any idea what `pkg_resources` might be and why your code expects it to exist, when it apparently doesn't?  It may be that the version of your program that was recovered was not the latest working version.

Comment: It would be nice to include the error in your question as a code block.

Comment: Well, I dont know what '''pkg_resources''' is but you probably need to import it first. so maybe add a line '''import pkg_resources'''